# how do I watermark images with text?

Tags: php, text, watermark

So I have code which pics up all the files from a directory, watermarks them and puts them in to another directory. I want to know how to get it to water mark my images with text, I have attempted this using imagettftext() but no luck.

Here is the working code

```
<?php
//Source folder where all images are placed
$source="myimages";

//Destination folder where all images with watermark will be copied
$destination="donewatermarks";

//Creating an image object of watermark image
$watermark=imagecreatefrompng("watermark.png");

//Margin of watermark from right and bottom of the main image
$margin_right=10;
$margin_bottom=10;

//Height ($sy) and Width ($sx) of watermark image
$sx=imagesx($watermark);
$sy=imagesy($watermark);

//Get list of images in source folder
$images=array_diff(scandir($source), array('..', '.'));

foreach($images as $image){
//Create image object of main image
$img=imagecreatefromjpeg($source.'/'.$image);

//Copying watermark image into the main image
imagecopy($img, $watermark, imagesx($img) - $sx - $margin_right, 
imagesy($img) - $sy - $margin_bottom, 0, 0, $sx, $sy);

//Saving the merged image into the destination folder
imagejpeg($img, $destination.'/'.$image,100);

//Destroying the main image object
imagedestroy($img);
}

//Destroying watermark image object
imagedestroy($watermark);

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I tried which currently returns an error

```
<?php
//Source folder where all images are placed
$source="watermarkitems";

//Destination folder where all images with watermark will be copied
$destination="donewatermarks";

//Creating an image object of watermark image
$watermark=imagecreatefrompng("watermark.png");

//Margin of watermark from right and bottom of the main image
$margin_right=10;
$margin_bottom=10;

//Height ($sy) and Width ($sx) of watermark image
$sx=imagesx($watermark);
$sy=imagesy($watermark);

$text = 'Testing...';

//Get list of images in source folder
$images=array_diff(scandir($source), array('..', '.'));

foreach($images as $image){
//Create image object of main image
$img=imagecreatefromjpeg($source.'/'.$image);

// Add the text
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

//Saving the merged image into the destination folder
imagejpeg($img, $destination.'/'.$image,100);

header('Content-Type: image/jpg');

//Destroying the main image object
imagedestroy($img);
}

//Destroying watermark image object
imagedestroy($watermark);

?>
```

Comment: *Here is the working code* - what about your attempt that failed? and what the problem with it? went through the manual at all? http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah ive been through the manual, if I add header(Content-type: image/png); I get a error message, and if i dont add it the images get moved without any water marking

Comment: can you post the tried code under your original code and the exact error message also Dave? this in your question of course ;-) I'm not at my dev pc right now, but I'll have a look at it when I get there. You also have been given an answer below, have you tried it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah the code below doesnt do watermarking as text

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

This code run for me you can try with this code.

```
<?php
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
$imageURL = imagecreatefrompng('bg.png');
$watermarkX = imagesx($watermark);
$watermarkY = imagesy($watermark);
imagecopy($imageURL, $watermark, imagesx($imageURL)/5, imagesy($imageURL)/5, 0, 0, $watermarkX, $watermarkY);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($imageURL);
imagedestroy($imageURL);
?>
```